# How do I say "most of the time" in Mandarin?

Tags: translation

大部分的时间？

大多数的时间？

Or some other phrase?

Comment: iciba：多数情况下，大多数时候，大部分时间，绝大部分时间（no 的）

Comment: ”的“ is not necessary to be indicative of adjective in Chinese. For example,  大部分时间=大部分的时间, and the former expression is more traditional. In fact the massive use of "的" is affected by western language, such as English. The same thing happened to the usage of "是"。For example,  “我是对的” used to be used when people what to emphasize on “对”, otherwise “我对” is the correct way to Chinese grammar to say "I am right.".

Comment: To follow onto what @WangZong'an said, one interpretation of something like "你是對的" would follow on after a belief that you were incorrect ("你以為你不對..."), and to correct that misapprehension.  Or, depending on emphasis, it could indicate that there are multiple people who could be right, and of those, it was you who was right.

Answer (score 2):

**一般**

*Tuttle Learner's*

> 1 generally speaking, ordinarily
>
> 每星期一上午我们一般都开会。
>
> Měi Xīngqīyī shàngwǔ wǒmen yìbān dōu kāihuì.
>
> We usually have a meeting every Monday morning.

*Guifan* defines this as:

> 3 形 占绝大多数的
>
> 学生们一般都很尊重老师。

占绝大多数的 can also include time here so there's no need to specifically emphasize *时间* unless you want/need to.

You can even opt for a **一般来说** if you're in the mood, which *KEY* defines as:

> generally speaking, generally, by and large

and *Guifan* gives the following example sentence:

> 一般来说, 雨天他是不会来的

Which roughly translates to something like:

> Usually, when it rains, he won't come.

Answer (score 2):

平时 or 平常 are two common expressions.

Answer (score 1):

通常。

Example: **通常**来说，“most of the time”翻译成“通常“是比较恰当的。

Answer (score 1):

Colloquially, it is also possible to say 多半, as in 多半的時間.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the length of time, then use `大部分时间`

If you mean `in most cases`, then use `大部分情况下`

(You can replace `大部分` with `大多数`)